# How to change a single value in firebase database multiple times?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to change  value of true and false to the opposite, so if the value in the database is true then it needs to be changed to false and if false then to true.

It works the first time i press the button but if i press the button again then it keeps changing nonstop until the app crashes.

Here is the code i use to change the value:

```
package com.example.myapplication.adapters

import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.myapplication.Model.CategoryModel
import com.example.myapplication.R
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener

class Category(private val listCategory: MutableList<CategoryModel>) : 
RecyclerView.Adapter<Category.ViewHolder>() {

val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
var currentUid = mAuth.currentUser?.uid
val myRef = database.getReference("User-following").child(currentUid!!)


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_layout, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}


    private fun fetchNotificationStatus(category: String, b: Boolean) {

        var status = if (b) {
            "true"
        } else {
            "false"
        }

        myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (childSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val key = childSnapshot.key
                    if (childSnapshot.child("category").value == category) {
                        myRef.child(key!!).child("notifications").setValue(status)
                        return
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.e("Database Error", error.toString())
            }
        })
    }







inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    var category: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category)
    var remove: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove)
    val alert: CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.alert)



    init {
        alert.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _: CompoundButton, _: Boolean ->
            val cat = category.text
            if (alert.isChecked) {
                 Snackbar.make(itemView,
                    "${category.text} has been added to your notifications list",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
                fetchNotificationStatus(cat as String, true)
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(itemView,
                    "${category.text} has been removed from your notifications list",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
                fetchNotificationStatus(cat as String, false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when you press the check box the first time it changes either from

```
false -> True or from true -> false
```

but if you press the check box again it keeps changing

```
 (false -> true -> false -> true -> false ...)
```

and doesn't stop changing until you close the app or until you press another button which causes the app to crash

How do i fix this so that it only changes to the opposite everytime the checkbox is pressed?

Comment: Please edit the question to show all relevant code.  We can't see what's in `fetchNotificationStatus`, nor can we see any code that writes to the database.  There needs to be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I have updated it above.

Comment: Your database listener is triggering itself by writing to the same location it's listening to.  I suggest rethinking what you want this code to do - it seems confusing to me.

Comment: i'm trying to change the value to the opposite each time the checkbox is pressed, Can you advise me on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple fix is to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener` in `fetchNotificationStatus`. Using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` ensures that the listener only gets one value and then stops listening. Your current `addValueEventListener` keeps listening to the data, so that it gets retriggered by your own write, which then writes it again, and again, and again...

---

In addition, I recommend using a query to find the node(s) that you want to modify:

```
private fun fetchNotificationStatus(category: String, b: Boolean) {

    var status = if (b) {
        "true"
    } else {
        "false"
    }

    Query query = myRef.orderByChild("category").equalTo(category);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (childSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                childSnapshot.getRef().child("notifications").setValue(status)
                // might be able to do .ref. instead of .getRef().
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e("Database Error", error.toString())
        }
    })
}
```

Using a query like this reduces the amount of data that your app reads and this reduces the bandwidth usage/cost both on the client and on the server.